# Mysqli prepared insert statements always returning false

Tags: php, mysql, statements

I'm writing prepared statements that are supposed to insert data into a table, on a database that's been pre-selected in the variable $GLOBALS['mysqli']. The connection has been tested, and that's not the problem I'm having. I'm only running into trouble whenever my prepared statement involves INSERT INTO. I know the tablename, and field names are correct, but $stmt is ALWAYS false. What gives?

```
$stmt = $GLOBALS['mysqli']->prepare("INSERT INTO audit_RefreshCount (user, count, lastrefresh) values (?,?,?)");
if ($stmt == TRUE) {
$stmt->bindParam('ssi', $_SESSION['username'], '0', time());
//$stmt->bind_Param('ssi', $_SESSION['username'], '0', time());     // Also doesn't work.
$stmt->execute();
}
```

Comment: For future reference, if you have a boolean in an if statement the `==TRUE` is redundant. `if($stmt)` would have been fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `if` condition is wrong, because `prepare` method returns either a `mysqli_stmt` class instance or `FALSE`.  So, you should test like:

```
if ($stmt !== FALSE) {
    $stmt->bind_param('ssi', $_SESSION['username'], '0', time());
    $stmt->execute();
} else {
    // Could not prepare statement
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that got me though into the block.